# when edit text click whole layout moves up

Tags: android

i do not want to move my layout which has several views in it so when user touch edit text then keyboard open and my layout widget goes up. I have even use code in manifest

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"

then

> android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"

Nothing work so please help me
Here is my xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeAdd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/black"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/my_toolbar">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rv_recycler_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/footer_layout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp_10"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_add_buddy_fragment"
                    android:visibility="visible" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/footer_layout"
            layout="@layout/footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: just try to remove all flags and try. Or with only adjustResize

Comment: try but is not worked @BabulPatel

Answer (score 1):

You have a `RecyclerView` in a `ScrollView`. Remove the parent `ScrollView`.

Add `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"` to AndroidManifest.xml for this activity.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your `ScrollView` with `**NestedScrollView**` in your XML Layout and define 
`android:windowSoftInputMode="ajustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"` in your manifest in particular activity

Answer (score 0):

Add below code to your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"/>
```